# Multidimensional array returning undefined after verifying array in console

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working on a Google Maps API script but having trouble working with my arrays. The screenshot below shows my console.log statements from the code below. There are two arrays, they look exactly how I want them. I then console.log to verify the length (in this case 6). I then start a loop from 0 to 5 (6 minus 1). But the verify first console.log after than (markers[i][0]) returns TypeError: x[r] is undefined. I'm baffled by why I can clearly see the array directly above where I'm trying to extract a value.

[image: screenshot]

```
if ($('#propertymap').length){
    var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('propertymap'), {
        center: {lat: 37.09024, lng: -95.712891},
        zoom: 5
    });
    var bounds=new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var geocoder=new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var id;
    var location;
    var street;
    var city;
    var state;
    var zip;
    var squarefootage;
    var ownedacreage;
    var leasedacreage;
    var hotelrooms;
    var website;

    var markers=[];
    var infocontent=[];

    $.post('/_getproperties.php', {task:'getproperties'}, function(result){
        var locationsSplit=result.replace('{', '').split('}');

        var i;
        for (i=0; i<locationsSplit.length-1; i++){
            var currentFields=locationsSplit[i].split('|');

            id=currentFields[0];
            location=currentFields[1];
            street=currentFields[2];
            city=currentFields[3];
            state=currentFields[4];
            zip=currentFields[5];
            squarefootage=currentFields[6];
            ownedacreage=currentFields[7];
            leasedacreage=currentFields[8];
            hotelrooms=currentFields[9];
            website=currentFields[10];

            geocodeAddress(location, street + ', ' + city + ', ' + state + ' ' + zip, location + '<br />' + street + '<br />' + city + ', ' + state + ' ' + zip, i);
        }

        console.log(markers);
        console.log(infocontent);
        console.log(locationsSplit.length-1);

        for (i=0; i<locationsSplit.length-1; i++){
            console.log(i);
            console.log(markers[i][0]);
        }
    });

    function geocodeAddress(locationtitle, locationaddress, locationdescription, i){
        geocoder.geocode({'address': locationaddress}, function(results, status){
            if (status==='OK'){
                markers[i]=[];
                markers[i][0]=locationtitle;
                markers[i][1]=results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                markers[i][2]=results[0].geometry.location.lng();

                infocontent[i]=[];
                infocontent[i][0]=locationdescription;
            } else {
                console.log('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I do notice that if I add console.log(markers.length) I get "zero" returned. I don't understand how I can view the array but still get "zero" for its length. I'm sure that is related to my problem?

Comment: Maybe you should `console.log('markers')` before what you think you're logging just so you're sure.

Comment: I tried that. I see the entire array as shown in the screenshot above. But then I still get length=0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`geocoder.geocode` appears to be an asyncronous operation.  At the time the program goes through the first iteration of the for loop the markers and infoContent arrays aren't populated yet.

The reason you're seeing results in the console as populated arrays is because the items are objects, and by the time manage to expand them they've been populated with data.  *The console is not displaying the data as it was at the point in time you called console.log, instead it's displaying the content of the object as it is at this moment*.

To verify this, instead of passing the markers instance to console.log, pass the *stringified* version by calling `console.log(JSON.stringify(markers))`.  I bet it'll show an empty array instead.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Perhaps this is a question for another post, but now I need to figure out how to wait until the asyncronous operations have all completed.

Comment: You can use Promise if you're not targeting older browsers.

Comment: I think I can add a function call inside the geocode call, which will determine if the last call has been made, and then continuing processing from that point. Thanks for your help!